# Ubuntu server: Cannot setup dummy driver alsa (LXC container) // modprobe issue

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, 19.10, lxc, modprobe

I'm trying to setup alsa on my ubuntu server, but it seems that the drivers are not installed & I don't know how to solve this problem. I just wanna setup a dummy soundcard. But I really don't know how to do it.

- `aplay -l` :

```bsh
aplay: device_list:272: no soundcards found...
```

- `lspci` :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05)
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x8) (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode]
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0)
00:1b.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #21 (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH LPC Controller (Z270)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation PCIe Data Center SSD (rev 02)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation PCIe Data Center SSD (rev 02)
06:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM2142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
```

- `alsa force-reload`:

```
alsa force-reload
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer (failed: modules still loaded: snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timermodprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.15.18-25-pve/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd-hda-codec-hdmi not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.18-25-pve
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.15.18-25-pve/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd-hda-codec-realtek not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.18-25-pve
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.15.18-25-pve/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd-hda-codec-generic not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.18-25-pve
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.15.18-25-pve/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd-hda-intel not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.18-25-pve
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.15.18-25-pve/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd-hda-codec not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.18-25-pve
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.15.18-25-pve/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd-hda-core not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.18-25-pve
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.15.18-25-pve/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd-hwdep not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.18-25-pve
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.15.18-25-pve/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:514 lookup_builtin_file() could not open builtin file '/lib/modules/4.15.18-25-pve/modules.builtin.bin'
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.15.18-25-pve/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd-timer not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.18-25-pve
 (failed).
```

- `modprobe snd-dummy`:

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.15.18-25-pve/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd-seq-dummy not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.18-25-pve
```

- `alsamixer` :

```
Cannot open mixer: No such file or directory
```

It seems that no drivers are installed. I cannot figure out what happened. I have no directory `/lib/modules` btw. It seems that all of them are in `/sys/modules`.

Also, my `uname -r` is `4.15.18-25-pve` which does not correspond to any linux-generic-`uname -r` etc... Well, I really don't know what's happening.

My os : ubuntu server 19.10

Comment: I updated to 19.10, the issue is still here.

Comment: I didn't know. I'm gonna flag this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution.

I needed an independent of host kernel, so now I use a KVM VPS instead of an LXC container. It is better in my case.